# Dialogfragment with multiple related layouts

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I want to display a dialog like a wizard style

It has layout1 and then clicking on next display layout2 with its functionality (with transition animation )

Can I create a `DialogFragment` with multiple `Fragments` in it? Or do I create multiple  `DialogFragments`? Or perhaps dialog fragment with one layout but nested views under it ?

Other better solution is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening multiple `DialogFragment` one after other does not have a good UX. you can use `transaction` inside the `DialogFragment` with animation on a root layout of the dialog.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animation.fade_in, android.R.animation.fade_out)
                    .replace(layout, fragment).addToBackStack(tag).commit()
```

but remember that you have to use `minWidth` , `minHeight` `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` on the root layout of the dialog, so it wont get bigger or smaller on transaction.

Comment: Can I chain the fragments in the fragmentdialog or does it have to be "lay out replace". It is because every layout has its complex business logic

Comment: Well, there is no need for chaining, you can use newInstance method by just start to typing newInstance method on all of the fragments and pass data between them while transacting. and using replace is for memory management, you can use add, if you want to put the layers on top of each others.